# Does changing the theme to a child theme affect a WP site in any way?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, child-theming

Thanks for taking a look at my question..

I'm using the divi theme which a fully functional, slightly complex site is running on. I really need to have a child theme because I need to edit some templates.

I'm really concerned that when I make the child theme and switch to it, the site will break... maybe some data or some layout will be lost?

Does my fears have any merit? Any info on this would be highly appreciated.

**THANKS!**

Answer (score 0):

Since both Divi and your new Child theme will have the divi builder available, I'd think you'd be safe.

I know that if you were to switch to a theme without the divi page builder, you would just see a bunch of short codes in your text area when editing pages.

Though I can't say with 100% certainty, I think that since you'd just being changing to the "same thing." You'd be safe.

To play it super safe though, if your site isn't too big, you can save each page as a divi template with all of the text saved within it as well.

Worst case scenario, you'd just have to select the correct pre-made template.